# Adding python matplotlib subplot to exiting plot doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to have two plots stacked up.
What I did so far is
I'm plotting live data this way:

```
    def animate(i):
    
        plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', labelleft=False, labelright=True)
        plt.cla()
        plt.plot(df.time, df.close)
        plt.plot(df.time, df.sma)   
        plt.plot(df.time, df.price_line, 'g-')    
        plt.title('ETHUSDT')
    
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval = 200)
        
plt.tight_layout()
    
plt.pause(0.001)
```

Result:
[image]

Now I add a sublot this way:

```
vola_ax = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
vola_ax.plot(df.time, df.volatility)
```

But the when I run the code I get first this:
[image]

Then it turns to this:

[image]

But my desired output is (roughly)this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please attach a complete example

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the figure and axes in the beginning:

```
def animate(i):
    
    ax0, ax1 = axs
    
    plt.cla()
    
    ax0.plot(df.time, df.close)
    ax0.plot(df.time, df.sma)   
    # ax0.plot(df.time, df.price_line, 'g-')    
    ax0.set_title('ETHUSDT')
    ax0.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', labelleft=False, labelright=True)

    ax1.plot(df.time, df.volatility)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 200)
        
plt.tight_layout()
    
plt.pause(0.001)
```

Comment: ax0 and ax1 are visible, but also an error is showing up. 'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'price_line'' ´ . the y axis values are on the left side from the ax0, should be on hte right side. ax1 has no data, only the pane

Comment: I edited so that the tick params are applied to the interested axes.
The error you are getting is not related to the plotting. it's just your dataframe not having a 'price_line' column. Check your data or provide a complete example.
If the solution for the plotting problem works, please consider accepting the answer, thanks.

Comment: something's still wrong. With each update (interval) there's a new window popping up

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating the two subplots separately when instantiating the figure and plotting the data on each `ax` object separately, as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nrow = 2; ncol = 1;
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 16), nrows=nrow, ncols=ncol)
ax = axs[0] # ie. the top subplot
df1.plox(ax=ax) # Apply FuncAnimation here as necessary

ax = axs[1] # ie. the bottom subplot
df2.plot(ax=ax) # Apply FuncAnimation here as necessary

# You can then apply common formatting through an iterator, eg common x limits:
for ax in axs:
   ax.set_xlim([0, 200])
```